# Filtering product attributes

Tags: attributes, filter

Rewriting this question as it's easier to look at the SQL queries, what I'm working on is to return all attributes at all times, so wether I am filtering by an attribute or not.

```
SELECT a.entity_id,a.attribute_id, a.value,cp.sku,COUNT(a.attribute_id) AS     count FROM catalog_product_index_eav AS a
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS cp ON a.entity_id = cp.entity_id
#WHERE (cp.type_id = 'bundle') AND (a.value IN('3394'))
GROUP BY a.value
```

So the above query returns all the attributes and their values but as soon as I add on the where statements, it's only returning the products with those attributes.

As i'm displaying all the attributes in a checkbox style, I need this to always return the full count.

Any ideas on how I need to amend the query to do this?

Comment: there are modules for that on Magento Connect like `GoMage Advanced Navigation` or `Ajax Multiple Attribute Filter`

Comment: Those modules don't work in this way whereby always showing all filters with a count for each option.